# deploy svn branch without version folder

Tags: svn, deployment, branch

Using Beanstalkapp, I deploy a branch to my staging environment. The branch has a name of "Version_1.0.0". I ftp into my staging environment and see that a "Version_1.0.0" folder has been created here also. How do I deploy files without having a branch name or version appear? Maybe I went about naming the branch in a wrong way, I just don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tweak your checkout command a bit.

Rather than doing:

```
svn checkout [path/to/my/reopo/branches/Version_1.0.0]
```

You need to add a `.` to the end (assuming you are in the directory you want the files to be checked out to). Like this:

```
    svn checkout [path/to/my/reopo/branches/Version_1.0.0] .
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure if this is the correct logic but I just changed my branch path before deployment to represent the 'current version' I'm working on. I don't have any control using Beanstalkapp but this deployed exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks for your response though.